# Timing early stopping in terms of epochs

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have model a neural network in Keras which attains a train set accuracy of 1 at epoch 1000 (on the used hyperparameters), yet the validation accuracy keeps fluctuating between 0.78 and 0.8.

I would like an Early Stopping command which monitors the validation accuracy but only starts after the 1000th epoch because, before the 1000th epoch, the validation accuracy keeps highly fluctuating. So my strategy is to maximize training set accuracy and then stop the learning as soon, as we encounter a high value for validation accuracy. (The theoretical best is 1.0 for training and 0.8 for validation)

Is such a callback function possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I updated the answer again, sorry I missed the epoch part. You need to define your own early stop function. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37296168/986546) to another question can help. 
Using that answer and changing a little using "epoch_threshold":

```
class EarlyStoppingByLossVal(Callback):
    def __init__(self, monitor='val_loss', value=0.00001, verbose=0):
        super(Callback, self).__init__()
        self.monitor = monitor
        self.value = value
        self.verbose = verbose
        self.epoch_threshold = 1000
    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs={}):
        current = logs.get(self.monitor)
        if current is None:
            warnings.warn("Early stopping requires %s available!" % self.monitor, RuntimeWarning)

        if current < self.value and epoch > self.epoch_threshold:
            if self.verbose > 0:
                print("Epoch %05d: early stopping THR" % epoch)
            self.model.stop_training = True
```

Comment: Yes, I have seen the callback function. However, the function has no argument to do what I am asking.

Comment: Can you provide a small guide on how such should be done?

Comment: Should I change this in original keras source file? Or can I run this in my own code? If it's the latter, I am getting a NameError

Comment: You need to show what is the error, you shouldn't change any Keras source file.

Comment: NameError: name 'Callback' is not defined. I tried changing Callback to callbacks, but then I get an error saying TypeError: module.__init__() takes at most 2 arguments (3 given)

Comment: Use "keras.callbacks.Callback"