# Keras, can we set it to keep fitting the model until the loss function be greater than one value or almost constant?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network

Instead of calling the fit method many times to count how many epoch is necessary to the model fit, can we say to `keras`, for example, we want the model to stop only when the loss function is less than `4e-4`, or if `x` epochs passed and the loss didn't change more than `1e-4`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. The "if x epochs passed and the loss didn't change more than 1e-4" is easily done with the [`EarlyStopping`](https://keras.io/api/callbacks/early_stopping/) callback:

```py
callbacks = [
  keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(min_delta=1e-4, patience=num_epochs_to_wait)
]
```

For the other part, you'll need a custom callback class [like the one from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37296168/3214872) that looks at the loss at the end of the epoch and stops the training if it's below the desired value.